# Spawn process that keeps running after app.quit()

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

How can I launch a user-defined application from an electron application. After the application is launched the electron application should quit, and restart after the program has finished. This to free system resources.

I was hoping to be able to use a child_process.spawn with detach option and unref.

```
let command= 'notepad.exe && ./electron.exe'
const launched_application = child_process.spawn(command,[],{detached:true,stdio:'ignore',shell:true})
launched_application.unref()
app.quit()
```

When the code hits app.close() the child_process is also killed. Is there a way to keep the child_process running after app.quit()

This also gives an arror on the && part, which I'm planning to fix using a .bat file. Any recommendations regarding this are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to relaunch app again then you should just close or hide all windows and activate setInterval to keep checking if child process is alive or not with help of pid ...
after that you can create new window again or show hidden window... and if you want fresh process then you should relaunch app after you get callback of user quitting that child application....